# Win32 - What is the proper way to use GDI objects?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am making a simple game in Win32.  Currently, I have most of my drawing object declared globally in the main file so that I never have to delete them or reload bitmaps.  So basically all of my bitmaps are loaded in WM_CREATE, and then nothing ever needs to be deleted - I was told by someone that I could just rely on the system to clean up my resources on project termination.  In WM_PAINT (which is called around 10 times a second), I have a lot of BitBlt() calls, as well as quite a few SelectObject() calls.  After running for about 10 - 15 minutes, SelectObject().  What would cause SelectObject() to fail, and am I using GDI object incorrectly?

EXAMPLE:

```
// Top of the file
HDC hdc;
HDC hdcmem;
HDC hbcmem;
HBITMAP colorsprites, blackwhitesprites, nums;
HBITMAP hdcold, hdcbmold, hdcbm;

// Some functions to get the window ready

// More variables used for drawing:
HBITMAP bg, side, mainCont, tmpbm, tmpold, bm_left, bm_right, sidebg, win_bm;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT rc;
HDC tmphdc;
HDC tmp;
HFONT font;
HBRUSH hbr;
HPEN pen;
BITMAP structBitmapHeader;
HGDIOBJ hBitmap;
HCURSOR crosshairs = LoadCursorW(hInst, IDC_CROSS);
HCURSOR normal = LoadCursorW(hInst, IDC_ARROW);
POINT cursor;
bool addPass = false, ignorePass;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            hdcbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom);
            hbcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcmem);
            hdcbmold = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcmem, hdcbm);

            // Load bitmaps
            bg                  = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BACKGROUND));
            mainCont            = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_GAME_CONT));
            side                = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SIDEINFO));
            colorsprites        = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_COLOR_SPRITES));
            blackwhitesprites   = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BLACKWHITE_SPRITES));
            sidebg              = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SIDEBG));
            nums                = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_NUMBERS));
            bm_left             = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_LEFT));
            bm_right            = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_RIGHT));
            win_bm              = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_VICTORY));
            if(bg == NULL || mainCont == NULL || side == NULL || colorsprites == NULL 
            || blackwhitesprites == NULL || sidebg == NULL || nums == NULL || bm_left == NULL 
            || bm_right == NULL)
                ThrowError("A bitmap failed to load.");

            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            // SelectObject() and BitBlt() are called a lot in here

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            // System will clean up all GDI stuff - no need to delete anything
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The shortest full example of code that exhibits this problem would be nice. An OS version might help as well.

Comment: And if you can cause it to fail faster, that would help a lot as well.

Comment: Sounds like a GDI leak, make sure you're calling `ReleaseDC` or `EndPaint` as appropriate.

Comment: "make sure you're calling ReleaseDC or EndPaint as appropriate. "

I've never definitely heard when that's appropriate.

I added an example of the layout of my main file with all my drawing function calls.

Comment: Naming your bitmaps starting with `hdc` is very confusing.

Comment: Good point.  I'll fix that, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Comment: @BrianGradin `ReleaseDC` should be called when you are finished with the result of `GetDC`.  More likely your leak is happening due to improper use of `SelectObject` in the code you *didn't* show, but you are missing a call to `ReleaseDC` in your `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say what I was going to say when I read the title. RAII can make it better.

Comment: You call `ReleaseDC` at the end of a block of code that calls `GetDC`, right?  Do I need to clean up after `CreateCompatibleDC`?

Comment: @BrianGradin, From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922550.aspx), *When you no longer need the memory device context, call the DeleteDC function to delete it.*

Comment: When I release hdc in WM_CREATE, nothing is drawn in WM_PAINT.

Comment: @BrianGradin, If memory serves, `BeginPaint` returns a DC to use that you need only call `EndPaint` to clean up.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that when you destroy a DC, you've selected the original bitmap back into it. You should never destroy a DC while your bitmap is still selected.

Comment: What do you mean by the "original" bitmap?  Do you mean I have to call SelectObject() right before deleting a DC if I loaded something into using SelectObject somwhere else?

Comment: @BrianGradin, `SelectObject` returns what you should keep a hold of and select back into it before you destroy it (or in the case of `WM_CREATE`, which uses `GetDC` instead of creating one, release it).

Comment: @BrianGradin, Found what I remembered. It's a good read on the topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/06/10399678.aspx

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding you correctly, if I have `HBITMAP hbm = SelectObject(hdc, bitmap); SelectObject(hdc, otherbitmap);`  I have to have `SelectObject(hdc, hbm);` BEFORE `DeleteDC(hdc)`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Or would I need to use `Release(hdc)`?

Comment: @BrianGradin, Yes, and if you create it, `DeleteDC`, if you obtain it, `ReleaseDC` (both the create functions and the obtaining function have the proper way to clean up in their docs), but you'll have to cast the result of `SelectObject` because you can't implicitly convert from a `void *` to another pointer. The two better options are `auto` and `SelectBitmap`.

Comment: @chris, that's a great link, thanks. I'm really grateful to Raymond Chen for creating that blog, and he checks in to StackOverflow from time to time.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I love reading knowledge that comes right from where the code is. Insights into how things actually work behind the scenes are always very interesting and insights into how much Windows takes care of broken applications at its own expense will never cease to sadden me. At least it's motivation to try to not become the author of such an application and end up not being able to reasonably fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make life a lot easier by calling SaveDC right after BeginPaint and RestoreDC just before EndPaint. This will restore the DC to its original state before it is freed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162945(v=vs.85).aspx